# Logging slow queries in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I added the following to **my.ini**

```
log_slow_queries  = "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\mysql-slow.log" 
long_query_time  = 3 
log-queries-not-using-indexes
```

I restarted the MySQL service . The slow queries are getting listed in `mysql-slow.log` but the issue is all the queries gets listed . I want to list only those queries which take more than 3 seconds

The following is an extract from `mysql-slow.log`:

```
# Query_time: 0  Lock_time: 0  Rows_sent: 29  Rows_examined: 29
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'tblRaw2%';
```

Here Query_time is listed as 0 I want only those queries which takes more than 3 seconds .
If there is any more fields to be set in my.ini please point out

Thanks

Comment: show tables command, mysql internally might treat this as queries not using index, do you have examples other that the above?

Comment: yes .. it happens for specific tables also. for eg i have a table by the name tblRaw20110823 and if I do 'select * from tblRaw20110823' it gets listed with Query_time: 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your database probably doesn't have `indexes` and you've defined that :

`log-queries-not-using-indexes` should be logged.

remove `log-queries-not-using-indexes` and try again.

Answer (score 3):

this might be helpful

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-queries-not-using-indexes

> If you are using this option with the slow query log enabled, queries that are expected to **retrieve all rows** are logged. See Section 5.2.5, “The Slow Query Log”. This option does not necessarily mean that no index is used. For example, a **query that uses a full index scan uses an index but would be logged because the index would not limit the number of rows**.

your both scenarios are just the cases

Answer (score 0):

In case you are looking for information related to how to log MySQL slow queries and analyze them, check my latest post on the subject at http://www.installationpage.com/mysql/mysql-importance-slow-log-processing/